# Javascript: Round up to the next multiple of 5

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I need a utility function that takes in an integer value (ranging from 2 to 5 digits in length) that rounds up to the **next** multiple of 5 instead of the **nearest** multiple of 5. Here is what I got:

```
function round5(x)
{
    return (x % 5) >= 2.5 ? parseInt(x / 5) * 5 + 5 : parseInt(x / 5) * 5;
}
```

When I run `round5(32)`, it gives me `30`, where I want 35.
When I run `round5(37)`, it gives me `35`, where I want 40.

When I run `round5(132)`, it gives me `130`, where I want 135.
When I run `round5(137)`, it gives me `135`, where I want 140.

etc...

How do I do this?

Comment: Should `round5(5)` give 5, or 10?

Comment: How about: divide x by 5, round up to the nearest integer (using the Math.ceil function) and then multiply by 5?

Comment: round5(5) should give 5

Answer (score 425, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
function round5(x)
{
    return Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5;
}
```

It's just a variation of the common rounding `number` to nearest multiple of `x` function `Math.round(number/x)*x`, but using `.ceil` instead of `.round` makes it always round up instead of down/up according to mathematical rules.

Comment: could you explain a little about how you came to this solution so fast? I thought Math.ceil only rounds up decimals to whole integers.

Comment: Well, it does round up to the whole integer here, @AmitErandole ;)

Comment: +1 for compact and efficient... and it will round to 10, right? :)

Comment: I'd add another parameter to this function, indicating the "rounder", so the original number can be rounded to whatever we set in the function call and not only fixed 5...

Comment: Watch out for input of x=0... This will cause an error.

Comment: @Nicolas for `x=0` it returns `0` as expected.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - a "divide by zero" waved it's arms in front of me but it isn't the case.

Comment: I love this solution! I implemented it with a closure for conveniently changing the multiple inline as needed: `const roundToNearestMultipleOf = m => n => Math.round(n/m)*m` Usage: `roundToNearestMultipleOf(5)(32)`

Comment: Arrow function version:

`const ceilToNearest = (value, increment) => Math.ceil(value / increment) * increment`. TypeScript version:
const ceilToNearest = (value: number, increment: number): number => Math.ceil(value / increment) * increment

Answer (score 46):

```
const roundToNearest5 = x => Math.round(x / 5) * 5
```

This will round the number to the nearest 5. To always round up to the nearest 5, use `Math.ceil`. Likewise, to always round down, use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`.
You can then call this function like you would any other. For example,

```
roundToNearest5(21)
```

will return:

```
20
```

Comment: +1 because I needed a way to round to the *nearest* five. (OP asked for rounding to the *next* five (upwards). Thus, the accepted answer is indeed correct, @Oliver.)

Comment: Just curious why don't use `Math.round()` ??

Answer (score 9):

Like this?

```
function roundup5(x) { return (x%5)?x-x%5+5:x }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, my unique situation needed a round up that didn't use floating point math but could use modulo.

Answer (score 4):

I arrived here while searching for something similar.
If my number is —0, —1, —2 it should floor to —0, and if it's —3, —4, —5 it should ceil to —5.

I came up with this solution:

```
function round(x) { return x % 5 < 3 ? (x % 5 === 0 ? x : Math.floor(x / 5) * 5) : Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5 }
```

And the tests:

```
for (var x = 40; x < 51; x++) {
  console.log(x+"=>", x % 5 < 3 ? (x % 5 === 0 ? x : Math.floor(x / 5) * 5) : Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5)
}
// 40 => 40
// 41 => 40
// 42 => 40
// 43 => 45
// 44 => 45
// 45 => 45
// 46 => 45
// 47 => 45
// 48 => 50
// 49 => 50
// 50 => 50
```

Comment: This can be accomplished more simply by using `Math.round`

Answer (score 3):

```
voici 2 solutions possibles :
y= (x % 10==0) ? x : x-x%5 +5; //......... 15 => 20 ; 37 => 40 ;  41 => 45 ; 20 => 20 ; 

z= (x % 5==0) ? x : x-x%5 +5;  //......... 15 => 15 ; 37 => 40 ;  41 => 45 ; 20 => 20 ;
```

Regards
Paul

Answer (score 2):

New answer for old question, without `if` nor `Math`

```
x % 5: the remainder
5 - x % 5: the amount need to add up
(5 - x % 5) % 5: make sure it less than 5
x + (5 - x % 5) % 5: the result (x or next multiple of 5)

~~((x + N - 1) / N): equivalent to Math.ceil(x / N)
```

```js
function round5(x) {
 return x + (5 - x % 5) % 5;
}

function nearest_multiple_of(N, x) {
 return x + (N - x % N) % N;
}

function other_way_nearest_multiple_of(N, x) {
 return ~~((x + N - 1) / N) * N;
}


console.info(nearest_multiple_of(5,    0)); // 0
console.info(nearest_multiple_of(5, 2022)); // 2025
console.info(nearest_multiple_of(5, 2025)); // 2025

console.info(other_way_nearest_multiple_of(5, 2022)); // 2025
console.info(other_way_nearest_multiple_of(5, 2025)); // 2025
```

Answer (score -1):

// round with precision

```
var round = function (value, precision) {
    return Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, precision)) / Math.pow(10, precision);
};
```

// round to 5 with precision

```
var round5 = (value, precision) => {
    return round(value * 2, precision) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const fn = _num =>{
    return Math.round(_num)+ (5 -(Math.round(_num)%5))
}
```

reason for using round is that expected input can be a random number.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using a while loop, or any other loop for that matter. What is important is to increase the number say n, until `n % 5 == 0;` Something like this

```
while(n % 5 != 0) {
    n++;
}
return n;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if( x % 5 == 0 ) {
    return int( Math.floor( x / 5 ) ) * 5;
} else {
    return ( int( Math.floor( x / 5 ) ) * 5 ) + 5;
}
```

maybe?

Comment: ReferenceError: `int` is not defined. Maybe you wanted `parseInt`, but this wouldn't be necessary since `Math.floor` returns a number.