# Javascript: Round Up to the Next Tens Place

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I have a javascript formula that rounds off the input number `number`.

```
var number = x;

alert (Math.round(number / 10) * 10);
```

This will output 11,12,13,14 as 10 and 15,16,17 as 20.

This is not what I want; I want to add 1 to 10 (11) and round it up, which will return/print 20.

Example:

- 11, 12 ,13, 14... 19 rounds to 20
- 21, 22... 29 rounds to 30
- etc.

Comment: use Math.ceil instead of Math.round

Comment: Sorry only saw this after I posted an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round up a number in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953384/javascript-round-up-to-the-next-multiple-of-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could use `Math.ceil` instead of `Math.round`.

Answer (score 2):

If what I'm interpreting your question as is indeed what you're asking, then you want Math.ceil instead.

This will equate to the ceiling of the function ("rounded up", if you will)

Therefore, your code becomes:

```
var number = x;

alert (Math.ceil(number / 10) * 10);
```

Comment: Man. I thought I posted this early. Didn't see the other answer.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it reverted (accidental ctrl-z?). Fixed it.