# Round the third decimal place to the nearest 5

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I'm new to Javascript but am trying to create a script to take a diameter, display only 3 decimal places and round the third decimal place to the nearest 5. I found some code which I think will do what I need to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953384/javascript-round-up-to-the-next-multiple-of-5) but can't work out how to add it to my existing code. I've added the third field as a check to make sure the result has been "rounded" correctly, can anyone point me in the right direction?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottrobson/kcvnp1pu/3/)

```
    function calculate() {
    var circBox = document.getElementById('circ').value;
    var diameterBox = document.getElementById('diameter');
    var diameterBox2 = document.getElementById('diameter2');
    var Diameter = circBox / 3.1416;
    var Diameter2 = Diameter.toFixed(5);
    var Diameter3 = Math.ceil(Diameter2 * 1000) / 1000;
    diameterBox.value = Diameter3;
    diameterBox2.value = Diameter2;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please reffer this

Comment: JS has a `Math.PI` property that you can use, it will be more precise than what you have here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can round to the nearest `0.005` value with

```
var Diameter3 = Math.round(Diameter2 * 200) / 200;
```