# Increment a counter by a user specified amount each time

Tags: jquery, numbers, counter, increment

I'm using the following code and am trying to work out how to increment a number by say 10 or 100 (a user-specified amount) until it reaches the `countTo` value.

The code below is working fine but incrementing by 1 each time.

```
function countUp() {
    $('.countup.counter span.number').each(function() {
        var num = jQuery(this), 
        countFrom = num.attr("data-from"), 
        countTo = num.attr("data-count"), 
        countIncrement = num.attr("data-increment"), 
        countSpeed = num.attr("data-duration");
        var decimal = 0;
        if (countTo.indexOf(".") > 0) { 
            decimal = countTo.toString().split(".")[1].length; 
        }
        $({ countNum: countFrom}).animate({ countNum: countTo }, {
            duration: parseInt(countSpeed), easing:"swing", 
            step: function() {
                num.text(parseFloat(this.countNum).toFixed(decimal));
            }, complete: function() {
                num.text(this.countNum);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

So for the example below I'd like it to count `0...100...200...300...400...500...600...700...800...900...1000.45`

```
<div class="counter"><span class="prefix">£</span><span class="number" data-increment="100" data-from="500" data-count="1000.45" data-duration="2000"></span><span class="suffix"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.animate` isn't the same as a `for (let i = countFrom; i<countTo; i+=countIncrement)` so you can't increment by an amount *over time*.

You either increment by an amount (as in the `for` above) or you animate over time.

Having said that, you *can* provide the output in increments, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953446/2181514):

```
var val = parseFloat(this.countNum);
num.text((Math.ceil(val/countIncrement)*countIncrement).toFixed(decimal));
```

Giving updated snippet:

```js
$('.counter span.number').each(function() {
  var num = jQuery(this), 
      countFrom = num.attr("data-from"), 
      countTo = num.attr("data-count"), 
      countIncrement = num.attr("data-increment"), 
      countSpeed = num.attr("data-duration");
  var decimal = 0;
  if (countTo.indexOf(".") > 0) { 
    decimal = countTo.toString().split(".")[1].length; 
  }
  $({ countNum: countFrom }).animate({ countNum: countTo }, {
    duration: parseInt(countSpeed), 
    easing:"swing", 
    step: function() {
      var val = parseFloat(this.countNum);
        num.text((Math.ceil(val/countIncrement)*countIncrement).toFixed(decimal));
    }, complete: function() {
      num.text(this.countNum);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="counter">
  <span class="prefix">£</span>
  <span class="number" data-increment="50" data-from="500" data-count="1000.45" data-duration="2000"></span>
  <span class="suffix"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did try something like this but was using parseFloat instead of Math.ceil which just ignored the increment value. I wonder why? e.g.        num.text((parseFloat(val/countIncrement/countIncrement) * countIncrement).toFixed(decimal));

Comment: You need to parseFloat *only* on the inner value.   Using on a float calculation does nothing or is too late - ie `parseFloat(txt) / 5` not `parseFloat(txt/5)`.   Ideally parseFloat when you first retrieve the data: `parseFloat(num.attr("data-from"))` then you don't need to worry about numerics after that (note: using `num.data("from")` will give you a numeric without needing any parseFloats.